# What are the times and medals for each Imperial Level?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

What are the times and medals for the items created in each Imperial level?

I would like to create a reference table for each item.

Comment: I've edited this to make it fit the question and answer format.  I turned the answer section into a community wiki, so don't worry that I'm attempting to steal your rep for the answer.  It's the format most questions like this tend to take so that more than one person can make contributions to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Blast Doors

  - Security Systems, 15min, x2 Medals, 190 credits
  - Improved Alloy, 35min, x3 Medals, 465 credits
- Blaster Repair (this level only has one kind of resource)

  - Barrel Replacement, 1h 50min, x5 Medals, 2545 credits
- Communications

  - Comlink, 1h 15min, x3 Medals, 1120 credits
  - Imperial Scout, 1h 25m, x4 Medals, 1695 credits
- Detention Level

  - Internal Forcefield, 1h 5min, x3 Medals, 1120 credits
  - Blaster Pistol, 1h 25min, x4 Medals, 1695 credits
- Droid Lab

  - Battle Droid, 1h 20min, x4 Medals, 1540 credits
  - Research Droid, 1h 40 min, x4 Medals, 2190 credits
- Droid Works

  - Repair Droid, 1h 20min, x4 Medals, 1540 credits
  - Medical Droid, 1h 40 min, x4 Medals, 2190 credits
- Emperor's Chamber

  - Imperial Edict, 1h 25min, x4 Medals, 1695 credits
  - Sith Spy, 1h 45 min, x4 Medals, 2365 credits
- Extending Bridge

  - Control Panel, 55min, x3 Medals, 875 credits
  - Security Force, 1h 15min, x4 Medals, 1395 credits
- Forcefield Gen

  - Shield Protector, 1h 30m, x4 Medals, 1855 credits
  - Heavy Shield, 1h 50 min, x5 Medals, 2545 credits
- Imperial Meeting

  - Battle Plan, 1h 5m, x3 Medals, 1120 credits
  - Assault Trooper, 1h 25min, x4 Medals, 1695 credits
- Interrogation

  - Recon Droid, 10min, x2 Medals, 145 credits
  - Armor Upgrade, 30min, x2 Medals, 385 credits
- Map Room

  - System Scan, 35min, x3 Medals, 465 credits
  - Probe Droid, 55m, x3 Medals, 875 credits
- Officer's Lounge

  - Inspections, 1h 20min, x4 Medals, 1540 credits
  - Imperial Gunners, 1h 40min, x4 Medals, 2190 credits
- Sith Meditation

  - Sith Droid, 1h 30 min, x4 Medals, 1855 credits
  - Sith Warrior, 1h 50 min, x5 Medals, 2545 credits
- Superlaser Ray

  - Cooling Coil, 1h 30m, x4 Medals, 1855 credits
  - Blaster Rifle, 1h 50 min, x5 Medals, 2545 credits
- Tractor Beam

  - Power Coupling, 35min, x3 Medals, 465 credits
  - Hull Armor, 55min, x3 Medals, 875 credits
- Turbo Laser

  - Capacitor Bank, 55min, x3 Medals, 875 credits
  - Heavy Turret, 1h 15m, x4 Medals, 1395 credits

Comment: There seems to have been another change/update. The cooling could now costs over 18000 coins and take over 5 hours. This list needs to be updated.